# How to optimize iterating a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I want to groupby dataframe column values based on ID and I have the following:

```
data = {
  "ID": ["1", "1", "2"],
  "start": [5, 6, 30],
  "end": [10,20,50],
  "label": ["age", "gender", "history"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The result i'm looking for is something like this:

```
Dict = {{'ID': 1, 'Labels': [[5,10,'age'], [6,20,"gender"]]}, {'ID': 2, 'Labels': [[30,50,'history']]} }
```

I tried multiple approaches and they all take extremally long, is there a way to optimize this code?

```
inner_dict = {}
inner_list = []
middle_list = []
labels_dict= []
for idx in df.index:

     ID = df['ID'][idx]
     for ddx in df.index:
          if (df['ID'][ddx] == ID):
               inner_list = [df['start'][ddx], df['end'][ddx],df['Label'][ddx]]
               middle_list.append(inner_list)
          else : 
               inner_dict = ({'ID': ID, 'Label': middle_list})
               # print (inner_dict)
               # inner_dict = ({'Label': inner_list})
               labels_dict.append(inner_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe inside a list comprehension and collect the Labels for each ID

```
s = df.set_index('ID')
[{'ID': k, 'Labels': g.values.tolist()} for k, g in s.groupby('ID')]
```

Result

```
[{'ID': '1', 'Labels': [[5, 10, 'age'], [6, 20, 'gender']]},
 {'ID': '2', 'Labels': [[30, 50, 'history']]}]
```